# NextJS and fetch interceptor working randomly

Tags: reactjs, next.js, interceptor, fetch-api

I'm trying to modify all my requests to /v1/* to https://api.treedis.com/v1/*. Now it works very well using fetch-intercept with this code:

```
fetchIntercept.register({
  request(url, _config) {
    const config = _config;
    const myHeaders = new Headers();

    if (!config.headers || !config.headers["Content-Type"]) {
      myHeaders.append("Accept", "application/json");
      myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }

    let finalUrl = null;
    if (url.indexOf("http") === -1) {
      const domain = process.env.REACT_APP_DOMAIN || "http://localhost:5030";
      finalUrl = `${domain}/${url}`;
    } else {
      finalUrl = url;
    }
    config.headers = myHeaders;
    return [finalUrl, config];
  },
})
```

`process.env.REACT_APP_DOMAIN` is set to api.treedis.com.

This file is being imported in _app.js

```
import App from "next/app";
import Head from "next/head";
import "../_helpers/auth-header";

class MyApp extends App {
  render = () => {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <Head />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </>
    );
  };
}

export default MyApp;
```

Now when I go to https://my.bc2e.com/tour/appartement-de-4-pieces-paris-5eme (my NextJS app), it tries to go to v1/public/getTour. On my browser it works perfectly, but on my client's it shows the following:
[image]

So the fetch-intercept doesn't work for him. When he cleans the cache it works and the interceptor kicks in, but then it stops working after couple of refreshes.

So it is quite random. Sometimes the interceptor would work and will add the `process.env.REACT_APP_DOMAIN`, and sometimes it wouldn't. I couldn't figure out why.

Any ideas here?

This NextJS app is hosted on CloudFront with Lambda@Edge doing the routing.

Comment: How are you injecting the environment variables into Next.js?

Comment: The environment variables are not the problem. I tried to hard-code the api string “https://api.treedis.com” to it and it still didn’t work. I wrote a console.log there, it seems that the interceptor is not being called on some cache refreshes. I suspect it’s a problem with CloudFront/Lambda but I’m not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it I replaced fetch with axios. I know this is not a real solution, but it solved this problem. I don't know what it was exactly that caused it.

Answer (score 0):

By default environment variables are only available in the `Node.js` environment, meaning they won't be exposed to the browser.

In order to expose a variable to the browser you have to prefix the variable with `NEXT_PUBLIC_.` For example:

`NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID=your_public_analytics_id`

it's a `next` kind of thing